# What is the difference between onClick handler approach

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given the below react component.

```
function App() {
    const [text, handleTextChange] = useState('Some Text');

    const handleChange = () => {
        handleTextChange('Button handler clicked');
    }       

    return (
       <>
        <span>{text}</span>
        <button onClick={handleChange}>Change Text</button>
       </>
    )
}
```

In the above component we can write onClick handler in two different ways

```
<button onClick={handleChange}>Change Text</button>
```

and

```
<button onClick={() => handleChange()}>Change Text</button>
```

which approach is better and why ?

Comment: I think its the same. But the first one pass the event as params. The second you can pass your own param.

Comment: What is this has to do with `angular` and `vue.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will work, and in this case, both will functionally be pretty much the same.

In your first example, you're *directly* passing the function reference to `onClick`

```
<button onClick={handleChange}>Change Text</button>
```

In your second example, you're passing an *anonymous* function to `onClick`. When called, that anonymous function calls `handleChange`

```
<button onClick={() => handleChange()}>Change Text</button>
```

Unless you're getting some parameters passed to `handleChange` that you don't want to, I'd suggest not wrapping it in an anonymous function like your second example. There's no benefit to it. It's just overhead.

Answer (score 1):

In the 2nd example you're creating 2 functions, we usually would want that in case we want to pass dynamic data to the inner function.

For example

In this example we are passing a function reference:

```
function App() {
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        // You have access to the click event object
        handleTextChange('Button handler clicked');
    }       

    return (
       <>
        <span>{text}</span>
        <button onClick={handleChange}>Change Text</button>
       </>
    )
}
```

But lets say you want to add a dynamic data, for example when iterating over a loop and you want to pass the index of each item:

```
function App() {
  const [text, handleTextChange] = useState('Some Text');

  const handleChange = (event, item) => {
    // we have access to both the event object and the specific item in the list
  };

  return items.map(item => {
    return (
      <div key={item}>
        <span>{text}</span>
        <button onClick={event => handleChange(event, item)}>
          Change Text
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```